# ActiveX - Automation Server Can't Create Object(onclick of button )

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, activex, com-interop

```
 function regist() 
         {
            var objBioBSP = new ActiveXObject('BioBSPCOMM.BioBSP');
         }
    <input type="button" onclick="regist()" 
            value="Click here" style="width: 304px"/>
```

i use above file to create activex object in my ASP.net project.
i ma calling above code onclick of button 
but when i use it gives error ActiveX - Automation Server Can't Create Object

Comment: Did you verify the progId is registered properly?  Did you implement IObjectSafety?

Comment: How i check ..i get an error on this line..var objBioBSP = new ActiveXObject('BioBSPCOMM.BioBSP'); i cant move further

Comment: i also chk dll is rgistered properly...and enable activeX script

Comment: Does your DLL get loaded?  If you set a breakpoint on your DllGetClassObject function, what happens?  Does it get called?  Does it return success and a valid COM object?  Did you implement IObjectSafety?